# Same result for Binary logistic regression and LASSO Logistic regression models

Tags: machine-learning, logistic

I use the same seed for binary logistic and LASSO logistic regression models to predict the same data. Finally I got the same results for both, which means same specificity, sensitivity and accuracy. Is it normal and what could be the reason of getting a same result? Thanks

Comment: Compare them in log loss. I have a hunch that they will differ.

Comment: How many predictors were included in the full logistic model and how many were retained in the LASSO model?

Comment: @EdM total 17 predictors excluding outcome variable in binary logistic regression. RFE choose 14 variables. In LASSO 14 retained as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the extreme of the lasso penalty being zero, the two models are the same. Likewise, a very small lasso penalty would result in very similar models. The difference in accuracy and other metrics premised on dichotomizing a continuous output is plausibly zero because the small difference in the model is not enough to shift an observation from one side of the dichotomy to the other. On the other hand, the log loss will probably be different because this calculation involves the entire predicted probability score, which will be different whenever $X\beta_\text{logistic} \neq X\beta_\text{lasso}$.

Comment: Why $X\beta_{logistic} \ne X\beta_{lasso}$ and not $\beta_{logistic} \ne \beta_{lasso}?$

Comment: @Dave Perhaps it's a bit fanciful, but I was imagining there could be a corner case where the coefficients are different, but the predictions remained the same, such as an increase in one coefficient *offsetting* the decrease in some combination of other coefficients.

Comment: @SycoraxsaysReinstateMonica The coefficients are different so as the features. But number of features remains the same for both.